# How to make a multi choice form field on app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-forms

I'm building an application on app Engine and I want to make a form field with multiple choices.
Here is my form (it uses django.newforms from the app engine sdk (django 0.96)) :

```
from google.appengine.ext.db import djangoforms
from django import newforms

class KeywordForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Keyword
        exclude = ['site', 'created_at', 'last_update']

    choices = [ (1, 'value1'), (2, 'value2'), (3, 'value3'), (4, 'value4') ]
    server = newforms.fields.MultipleChoiceField(choices = choices)
```

The problem is : when I submit the form (with one or more values selected) I've this validation error : "**Enter a list of values.**"

I don't understand why... some help on this problem will be very appreciated.
Thanks ! :)

*Edit (extra informations) :*
Here is the form validation code :

```
 form = forms.KeywordForm(data=self.request.POST)
 if form.is_valid():
     ...
```

self.request.POST :

```
UnicodeMultiDict([(u'keyword', u'test'), (u'server[]', u'1'), (u'server[]', u'2')])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution !

The problem is *self.request.POST* dictionnary provided to my form's constructor.
It's format is not appreciated by *MultipleChoiceField.clean()* function, so I transformed it.

Here is the working validation code :

```
 args = self.request.arguments()
 data = {}
 for i in args:
     data[i] = self.request.get_all(i)
 form = forms.KeywordForm(data=data)
 if form.is_valid():
     [...]
```

Comment: You can simply pass self.request.POST.items().

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick, it's a lot more elegant !

Comment: @Nick Johnson I am getting same problem. Will you please help? Here is my form http://dpaste.org/a8FZc/ thanks

Comment: @NickJohnson I also tried. `form = IdentityForm(data=self.request.POST.items())` But getting another error. `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`